How to setup Windows 11 to background images as slideshow from a folder permanently?
In Windows 11, I want the background image to be shown from a folder, so I go to "Settings" -> "Personalization" -> "Personalize your background" and select "slideshow" and a folder with images. Then Windows 11 shows background images from the slideshow.
But when I restart the computer, the setting is back to "Picture", and I have to change this setting again.

How to make it permanent so Windows 11 shows the images from the defined folder, and does not change back again?
Also, "Sync" is not available for my account.

I did save the "theme" but it did not work. After a reboot of the laptop at first the background images were from that folder, but only 1-2 minutes later to be replaced by the "standard" windows 11 pictures.
The system itself is up-to-date, it has been updated from windows 10 to windows 11 last week.
Then I tried to rename the folder with the background pictures, and now when I go to "Personalization" -> "Background" and under "Personalize your background" I choose "slideshow", that drop-down goes immediately back to "picture".
Where can I report a windows 11 bug? If that is even possible?

It should be "permanent" by default. I have never observed a case where Windows reverts this setting, in any of the versions of Windows that has supported this feature. Is this a business environment? If it is not a business environment and this is a personal computer, you should proceed with the normal Windows Repair functions well documented on this and other sites as a first step.

Some people suggest making sure there are no folders inside the slideshow folder. Others note that saving the settings as a Theme resolved this issue for them. Have you tried either of these methods yet?

Try to set the slideshow using the classic Desktop Background customizer -
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper
Use the Run dialogue box (Win + R) to paste above code and click OK.

This 100% sounds like forced setting from a business machine, is it? @music2myear asked this in a comment which you haven't addressed which makes me a bit suspicious. Things you could check to confirm if this setting is being applied to your PC from a business:

Check if your PC is on a business domain network:

Method 1: Start button, type & click Control Panel, Navigate to System and Security, and then click System.
Method 2: Settings, About, look for 'domain'
Method 3: Settings, Accounts, Access work or school, look for 'domain'
Method 4: from command prompt run dsregcmd /status (documentation)


Local Group Policy, look in these settings:

User Configuration\ Administrative Templates\ Desktop\ Desktop\
Desktop wallpaper


Look in registry (regedit.exe) for these keys:
HKCU=HKEY_CURRENT_USER; HKLM=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System --wallpaperStyle

Other areas that aren't as likely:

Computer Configuration\ Administrative Templates\ Control Panel\ Personalization\ Force a specific Start background
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization: --ForceStartbackground; PersonalColors_Accent; NoChangingWallPaper;
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop: -NoHTMLWallPaper
Documentation: GPOlookup (search wallpaper or background at top then focus on keyname & Id to relate for registry locations to check), intune/mdm settings (focus on the 'registry' info)


From command prompt rsop (documentation). Alternative method: from command prompt mmc, file, add/remove snap-in, result set of policy, add, OK. Navigate through this looking for anything mentioning background, wallpaper, etc.



It is a work laptop, but on Windows 10 on the same laptop choosing my own background images worked without problem. I do not find any 'domain' entry on the System settings and in the Policies regedit I only see the entry "(Default)   REG_SZ   {value not set)`.

You CAN design a GPO policy to apply ONLY to a certain OS. 1) You're 100% sure its not part of a domain in any of those areas? 1a) Can you run the following from command prompt dsregcmd /status? 2) You looked in both registry locations? 3) Have you reached out to your businesses IT department to see their thoughts? I could have you check other location (rsop from command-prompt or mmc.exe then add snap-in, result set of policy) but that usually only matters for PC's on the domain

Updated my answer with some more places to check if desired

You can try installing the Dynamic Theme app from the Microsoft Store. It's a third-party app with a similar interface to the default windows settings, and it often fixes common issues like this.
You can check it out on the Microsoft Store here:
https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nblggh1zbkw?hl=en-US&gl=US

I have same issue but with Date Time Format, whenever I change my pc's date time format from setting in Windows 11, after reboot it reset again with old format.
Solution:

Go to Settings > Accounts > Windows Backup
Settings

Uncheck "Personalization" from "Remember my preferences" list or you can disable whole section.
Remember my preferences


Try this solution, may be work for you as well.

This is veery abnormal, so it might be a bug.
Here are some things that you could try.

Update your system
Reboot
Save as a theme
Make another folder with your pictures, and place them all in the new folder and select the new folder in settings.
See if any OTHER type of backup or sync option is reverting this.

There isn't much else... D:
